# UWP c# TreeView with icons example

Tags: c#, uwp, treeview

Microsoft recently started supporting the TreeView for UWP. This page is a reference.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view

They display there an example with icons however they do not provide an example of how to do this.

Can anyone show an example of how to do this in XAML or programmatically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's stated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view#tree-view-node-content > you can just add anything in the content and need to provide a DataTemplate for it's representation! ( So like how a ListView works )

Comment: Have you tried it? I read that statement and for a ListView the <DataTemplate> is embedded in a <ListBox.ItemTemplate>. The <TreeView.ItemTemplate> does not exist. Hence, and example would be wonderful. I only wish their documentation could have provided an example.  Still researching an example. By example, I am referring to complete working code example as I stated in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I copied the example (very bottom of the page) from the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view#tree-view-node-content) provided by [Depechie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613087/depechie) and replaced the DataTemplate with this code below and it worked. I am now able to see the Image.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TreeViewItemDataTemplate">
            <Grid Height="44">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image x:Name="TreeIcon" Width="16" Height="16" Source="Assets/folder.png" Margin="0,0,10,0">
                        <Image.FocusVisualPrimaryBrush>
                            <ImageBrush/>
                        </Image.FocusVisualPrimaryBrush>
                    </Image>
                    <TextBlock
                    Text="{Binding Content.DisplayName}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```